# Strange "freezing" behaviour in Excel 2013 brand new XPS 13

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, freeze, microsoft-excel-2013, dell-xps

I have a new XPS 13 with 16 GB mem, i7, windows 10 64bit and since I got it a few weeks ago I have been having the following very annoying problem.

At random times the excel GUI disappears, although it seems to happen quite a bit when the screen comes on after the laptop has been on but with screen off for a while. This does also happen with the DA200 not connected which would point to video driver.

When I click File upper left hand no text is visible also the whole menu bar is missing text and the cells freeze up, not that you could do much with the whole GUI missing.

Now you could say this is an Excel issue and not Dell XPS 13 issue but the resolution of this is to either disconnect my external VGA monitor or reconnect the external monitor. Once this is done Excel immediately goes back to normal. In cases where I am not using an external monitor disconnecting and reconnecting the DA200 hub (with at that time only network cable connected) also does the trick.

Note this behavior also happens with many Excel spreadsheet open but that is the way I work and did with my 7 year old previous laptop.

So there appears to be an issue with the DA200 connector/driver, the video driver or something unrelated.. By the way it also happens but less frequently when the DA200 is not connected and no external monitor is used. The computer will recover after a while but takes some time.

I migrated from a 7 year old Dell E4300 and NEVER had any problems like this and am very disappointed that this is now happening on the new machine. The old machine had the exact same Excel 2013 64 bit.

See attached JPG to see what it looks like when this happens.

Any suggestions on how to fix/avoid this issue?

[image]

Comment: try to disable animation features in excel

Comment: Tried that but does not help and these features were also on, on my 7 year old laptop that worked fine with excel 2013 and anyway on brand new I7 cpu should not be required

Answer (score 0):

I have the XPS13(2015) and XPS13(9350 or Skylake), both in core i7. You mention the DA200 adapter which is only supported by the USB-C ThunderBolt 3 port on the XPS13(9350).

IMO, the problem is with the ThunderBolt 3 driver/firmware on the XPS13(9350). There are numerous reports such as yours relating to poor ThunderBolt operation. I had the Dell TB15 ThunderBolt dock and my multi-display setup would blank out every so often. Someone documented the glitch on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/8Ghd802OOxM). When I ran the same multi-display using the Dell D3100 USB3, I had no problems. I also found when I attached a M.2 external SSD to the USB3 port, I would experience ~260MB/s transfer rate, but when attached to ThunderBolt port it only transferred at ~30MB/s, much less than spec.

Dell has released a handful of driver and firmware updates to address the ThunderBolt problem. To date, they haven't solved my problems. I believe Dell will get it sorted out in time, but for now I'm using the stable USB3 variants. The USB3 variant of the DA200 is the H5G60.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the heads up...quite poor of Dell to sell high end laptops and accessories that do not work...I will contact them as well for suitable solution i.e. DA100 or H5G60